# how can i shorten this Program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have made Ultimate Tic Tac Toe, it works fine but has over 200 lines of code of which most of it is repeated, I'm not sure on how I should use arrays I have tried but failed. so I removed it
Here's the code in parts( ive had to remove most of the code because it was at 76768 characters) Sorry if it's too long

```
Public Class Form1
Dim count, temp, ch, temp2, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9
Dim listOfTextBox As New List(Of TextBox)
Public Sub Start_UP() Handles Me.Load
    Disable_ALL()
End Sub
Private Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click
    cmdStart.Enabled = False
    Enable_ALL()
    Winner_Display.Text = Nothing
    ch = 1
    count = 0
    temp = 0
    temp2 = 0
    v1 = "0"
    v2 = "0"
    v3 = "0"
    v4 = "0"
    v5 = "0"
    v6 = "0"
    v7 = "0"
    v8 = "0"
    v9 = "0"
End Sub 'start
Public Sub totalcheckwin()
    If v1 = "O" And v2 = "O" And v3 = "O" Or
        v4 = "O" And v5 = "O" And v6 = "O" Or
        v7 = "O" And v8 = "O" And v9 = "O" Or
        v1 = "O" And v4 = "O" And v7 = "O" Or
        v2 = "O" And v5 = "O" And v8 = "O" Or
        v3 = "O" And v6 = "O" And v9 = "O" Or
        v1 = "O" And v5 = "O" And v9 = "O" Or
        v3 = "O" And v5 = "O" And v7 = "O" Then
        Disable_All()

 Winner_Display.Text = "O Wins"
    End If
    If v1 = "X" And v2 = "X" And v3 = "X" Or
        v4 = "X" And v5 = "X" And v6 = "X" Or
        v7 = "X" And v8 = "X" And v9 = "X" Or
        v1 = "X" And v4 = "X" And v7 = "X" Or
        v2 = "X" And v5 = "X" And v8 = "X" Or
        v3 = "X" And v6 = "X" And v9 = "X" Or
        v1 = "X" And v5 = "X" And v9 = "X" Or
        v3 = "X" And v5 = "X" And v7 = "X" Then
        Disable_All()

        Winner_Display.Text = "X Wins"
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub checkcount()
    Hiden_texbox.Focus()

    count = count + 1
    If count = 3 Then
        count = 1
    End If
    If count = 1 Then
        temp = "O"
    Else
        temp = "X"
    End If
    locksqure()
End Sub 'locks squres
Public Sub locksqure()

    If temp2 = "sq1" Then
        If v1 = "O" Or v1 = "X" Then
            Enable_All
            Disable_A()
        Else
            Disable_All
            Enable_A()
        End If
    End If
    If temp2 = "sq2" Then
        If v2 = "O" Or v2 = "X" Then
            Enable_All()
            Disable_B()
        Else
            Disable_All()
            Enable_B()
        End If
    End If
    ' you should get the drift of this bit of code
    permlock()
    totalcheckwin()
End Sub
Public Sub permlock()
    If TextBox1.Text = "O" Or TextBox1.Text = "X" Then
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
    End If
'this code repeats till the textbox is at 81
End Sub

Public Sub Disable_ALL()
    Disable_A()
    Disable_B()
    Disable_C()
    Disable_D()
    Disable_E()
    Disable_F()
    Disable_G()
    Disable_H()
    Disable_I()
End Sub
Public Sub Disable_A()
    For value As Integer = 1 To 9
        dim textbox as new TextBox
        textbox.Name= "TextBox"+value.tostring 
        listOfTextBox.add(textbox) 

           If (value = 9) Then
                Exit For
           End If
    Next

     listofTextBoxes.ForEach(Sub(o)
                            o.BackColor = Color.lightGray
                            o.Enabled = False
                            o.Name = "TextBoxId"
                            End Sub)
End Sub 'disable squre
'This part repeats 9 times and the textbox court goes to 81
Public Sub Enable_ALL()
    Enable_A()
    Enable_B()
    Enable_C()
    Enable_D()
    Enable_E()
    Enable_F()
    Enable_G()
    Enable_H()
    Enable_I()
End Sub
Public Sub Enable_A()
    For value As Integer = 1 To 9
        dim textbox as new TextBox
        textbox.Name= "TextBox"+value.tostring 
        listOfTextBox.add(textbox) 

           If (value = 9) Then
                Exit For
           End If
    Next

     listofTextBoxes.ForEach(Sub(o)
                            o.BackColor = Color.White
                            o.Enabled = True
                            o.Name = "TextBoxId"
                            End Sub)
End Sub 'enable squre
'This part repeats 9 times and the textbox court goes to 81
'the next part just checks if a person has got 3 in a row  and repeats 9 times 
    Public Sub checkwin()
    If TextBox1.Text = "O" And TextBox2.Text = "O" And TextBox3.Text = "O" Or
        TextBox4.Text = "O" And TextBox5.Text = "O" And TextBox6.Text = "O" Or
        TextBox7.Text = "O" And TextBox8.Text = "O" And TextBox9.Text = "O" Or
        TextBox1.Text = "O" And TextBox4.Text = "O" And TextBox7.Text = "O" Or
        TextBox2.Text = "O" And TextBox5.Text = "O" And TextBox8.Text = "O" Or
        TextBox3.Text = "O" And TextBox6.Text = "O" And TextBox9.Text = "O" Or
        TextBox1.Text = "O" And TextBox5.Text = "O" And TextBox9.Text = "O" Or
        TextBox3.Text = "O" And TextBox5.Text = "O" And TextBox7.Text = "O" Then

        TextBox1.Text = "O"
        TextBox2.Text = "O"
        TextBox3.Text = "O"
        TextBox4.Text = "O"
        TextBox5.Text = "X"
        TextBox6.Text = "O"
        TextBox7.Text = "O"
        TextBox8.Text = "O"
        TextBox9.Text = "O"
        Disable_A()
        v1 = "O"
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text = "X" And TextBox2.Text = "X" And TextBox3.Text = "X" Or
        TextBox4.Text = "X" And TextBox5.Text = "X" And TextBox6.Text = "X" Or
        TextBox7.Text = "X" And TextBox8.Text = "X" And TextBox9.Text = "X" Or
        TextBox1.Text = "X" And TextBox4.Text = "X" And TextBox7.Text = "X" Or
        TextBox2.Text = "X" And TextBox5.Text = "X" And TextBox8.Text = "X" Or
        TextBox3.Text = "X" And TextBox6.Text = "X" And TextBox9.Text = "X" Or
        TextBox1.Text = "X" And TextBox5.Text = "X" And TextBox9.Text = "X" Or
        TextBox3.Text = "X" And TextBox5.Text = "X" And TextBox7.Text = "X" Then

        TextBox1.Text = "X"
        TextBox2.Text = "O"
        TextBox3.Text = "X"
        TextBox4.Text = "O"
        TextBox5.Text = "X"
        TextBox6.Text = "O"
        TextBox7.Text = "X"
        TextBox8.Text = "O"
        TextBox9.Text = "X"
        Disable_A()
        v1 = "X"
    End If
    locksqure()
End Sub

   Private Sub resetall()
    Enable_All()
End Sub
Private Sub retext()
    TextBox1.Text = Nothing
    TextBox2.Text = Nothing
    TextBox3.Text = Nothing
' goes till textbox is at 81
        End Sub
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ch = 0
    resetall()
    retext()
    cmdStart.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq1"
        checkcount()
        TextBox1.Text = temp
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub '1 squre
Private Sub TextBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq2"
        checkcount()
        TextBox2.Text = temp
        TextBox2.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq3"
        checkcount()
        TextBox3.Text = temp
        TextBox3.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq4"
        checkcount()
        TextBox4.Text = temp
        TextBox4.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq5"
        checkcount()
        TextBox5.Text = temp
        TextBox5.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox6.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq6"
        checkcount()
        TextBox6.Text = temp
        TextBox6.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox7.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq7"
        checkcount()
        TextBox7.Text = temp
        TextBox7.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox8.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq8"
        checkcount()
        TextBox8.Text = temp
        TextBox8.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox9.Click
    If ch = 1 Then
        temp2 = "sq9"
        checkcount()
        TextBox9.Text = temp
        TextBox9.Enabled = False
        checkwin()
    End If
End Sub
'this repeats 9 for a total 81 textbox's
```

End Class

[Heres an image of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1onZy.png)

Comment: One of the easiest suggestion is, when you want to disable all except one, you could call Disable_All() followed by Enable_A() for example.

Comment: I'm working on it - I dont have a huge amount of free time, each day, but I'm on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Done - i think - The code assumes that your text boxes are on your form in a particular order like this

```
1   2   3   10  11  12  19  20  21  
4   5   6   13  14  15  22  23  24
7   8   9   16  17  18  25  25  27
28  29  30  37  38  39  46  47  48
31  32  33  40  41  42  49  50  51
34  35  36  43  44  45  52  53  54
55  56  57  64  65  66  73  74  75
58  59  60  67  68  69  76  77  78
61  62  63  70  71  72  79  80  81
```

Oh - and including my comments the file is now only around 17000 bytes :)

```
' OK. I hope you dont mind, but I've altered a couple of names to make the game more
'maintainable if you come back to it in six months time :)

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    'removed several variables that are now unused in the revised code
    Dim games(8, 2, 2) As TextBox
    Dim _count, _ch, _currentGameId As Integer
    Dim _gameStatus(8) As EnumGameStatus
    Dim _currentplayer As String

    Private Enum EnumGameStatus
        XWin
        OWin
        Incomplete
        Draw
    End Enum

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        InitializeArray()
        initializeClickHandlers()
        Disable_All()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeArray()
        Dim txtboxes As New List(Of TextBox)
        For Each txtbx As Object In Controls
            Dim tbox As TextBox
            If TypeOf txtbx Is TextBox Then
                tbox = CType(txtbx, TextBox)
                If tbox.Name.Contains("TextBox") Then
                    txtboxes.Add(tbox)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Dim txtboxnum As Integer
        Dim txtboxname As String
        For game As Integer = 0 To 8
            For line As Integer = 0 To 2
                For box As Integer = 0 To 2
                    For i As Integer = 0 To 80
                        txtboxnum = game * 9 + line * 3 + box + 1
                        txtboxname = "TextBox" & txtboxnum.ToString
                        If txtboxes(i).Name = txtboxname Then
                            games(game, line, box) = txtboxes(i)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Disable_All()
        For Each tbox As TextBox In games
            tbox.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            tbox.Enabled = False
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Enable_All()
        For gameId As Integer = 0 To 8
            Enable_Game(gameId)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Disable_Game(gameId As Integer)
        For line As Integer = 0 To 2
            For column As Integer = 0 To 2
                games(gameId, line, column).Enabled = False
                games(gameId, line, column).BackColor = Color.LightGray
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Enable_Game(gameId As Integer)
        For line As Integer = 0 To 2
            For column As Integer = 0 To 2
                With games(gameId, line, column)
                    If .Text = "" Then
                        games(gameId, line, column).Enabled = True
                        games(gameId, line, column).BackColor = Color.White
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click
        cmdStart.Enabled = False
        Enable_All()
        Winner_Display.Text = Nothing
        _ch = 1
        _count = 0
        _currentGameId = 0
        _gameStatus =
            {EnumGameStatus.Incomplete, EnumGameStatus.Incomplete, EnumGameStatus.Incomplete, EnumGameStatus.Incomplete,
             EnumGameStatus.Incomplete, EnumGameStatus.Incomplete, EnumGameStatus.Incomplete, EnumGameStatus.Incomplete,
             EnumGameStatus.Incomplete}
    End Sub

    Private Sub TotalCheckWin()
        If _
            (_gameStatus(0) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(1) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(2) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(3) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(5) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(6) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(7) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(8) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(0) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(3) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(6) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(1) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(7) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(2) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(5) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(8) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(0) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(8) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(2) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.OWin And _gameStatus(6) = EnumGameStatus.OWin) Then
            Disable_All()
            Winner_Display.Text = "O Wins"
        End If
        If _
            (_gameStatus(0) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(1) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(2) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(3) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(5) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(6) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(7) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(8) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(0) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(3) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(6) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(1) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(7) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(2) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(5) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(8) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(0) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(8) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Or
            (_gameStatus(2) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(4) = EnumGameStatus.XWin And _gameStatus(6) = EnumGameStatus.XWin) Then
            Disable_All()
            Winner_Display.Text = "X Wins"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub NextPlayer()
        _count = _count + 1
        If _count = 3 Then
            _count = 1
        End If
        If _count = 1 Then
            _currentplayer = "O"
        Else
            _currentplayer = "X"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MarkGameOWin(gameId As Integer)
        For line As Integer = 0 To 2
            For column As Integer = 0 To 2
                games(gameId, line, column).Text = "O"
                games(gameId, 1, 1).Text = "X"
            Next
            _gameStatus(gameId) = EnumGameStatus.OWin
            Disable_Game(gameId)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub MarkGameXWin(gameId As Integer)
        games(gameId, 0, 0).Text = "X"
        games(gameId, 0, 1).Text = "O"
        games(gameId, 0, 2).Text = "X"
        games(gameId, 1, 0).Text = "O"
        games(gameId, 1, 1).Text = "X"
        games(gameId, 1, 2).Text = "O"
        games(gameId, 2, 0).Text = "X"
        games(gameId, 2, 1).Text = "O"
        games(gameId, 2, 2).Text = "X"
        _gameStatus(gameId) = EnumGameStatus.XWin
        Disable_Game(gameId)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MarkGameDraw(gameId As Integer)
        games(gameId, 0, 0).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 0, 1).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 0, 2).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 1, 0).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 1, 1).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 1, 2).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 2, 0).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 2, 1).Text = ""
        games(gameId, 2, 2).Text = ""
        _gameStatus(gameId) = EnumGameStatus.Draw
        Disable_Game(gameId)
    End Sub

    Private Function CheckWin(gameId As Integer) As EnumGameStatus
        CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.Incomplete
        Dim _loopOnce As Boolean = True
        Do
            'check for horizontal win
            For line As Integer = 0 To 2
                If games(gameId, line, 0).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, line, 1).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, line, 2).Text = "X" Then
                    CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.XWin
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf _
                    games(gameId, line, 0).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, line, 1).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, line, 2).Text = "O" Then
                    CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.OWin
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Next
            'check for vertical win
            For column As Integer = 0 To 2
                If games(gameId, 0, column).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, 1, column).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, 2, column).Text = "X" Then
                    CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.XWin
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf games(gameId, 0, column).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, 1, column).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, 2, column).Text = "O" Then
                    CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.OWin
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Next
            'check for Left to right diagonal win
            If games(gameId, 0, 0).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, 1, 1).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, 2, 2).Text = "X" Then
                CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.XWin
                Exit Do
            ElseIf games(gameId, 0, 0).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, 1, 1).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, 2, 2).Text = "O" Then
                CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.OWin
                Exit Do
            End If
            'check for Right to Left diagonal win
            If games(gameId, 2, 0).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, 1, 1).Text = "X" AndAlso games(gameId, 0, 2).Text = "X" Then
                CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.XWin
                Exit Do
            ElseIf games(gameId, 2, 0).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, 1, 1).Text = "O" AndAlso games(gameId, 0, 2).Text = "O" Then
                CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.OWin
                Exit Do
            End If
            'check if all squares filled with no winner
            'altered this  to check for a draw if no squares were left
            'instead of using gamemove in my previous code
            Dim squaresLeft As Integer = 9
            For line As Integer = 0 To 2
                For column As Integer = 0 To 2
                    If games(gameId, line, column).Text <> "" Then
                        squaresLeft -= 1
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            If squaresLeft = 0 Then
                CheckWin = EnumGameStatus.Draw
            End If
        Loop Until _loopOnce = True
        'return values and update game status ad movex
        _gameStatus(gameId) = CheckWin
        Return CheckWin
    End Function

    Private Sub ResetAll()
        For gameId As Integer = 0 To 8
            Disable_Game(gameId)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Retext()
        For gameId As Integer = 0 To 8
            For line As Integer = 0 To 2
                For column As Integer = 0 To 2
                    games(gameId, line, column).Text = Nothing
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        _ch = 0
        Retext()
        ResetAll()
        cmdStart.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCurrentGame(clickedTextBox As TextBox) As Integer
        Dim txtboxnum As Integer = (CInt(Regex.Match(clickedTextBox.Name, "\d+").Value) - 1)
        GetCurrentGame = txtboxnum \ 9
    End Function

    'added this to work out which the next game block should be
    Private Function GetNextGame(clickedTextbox As TextBox) As Integer
        Dim txtboxnum As Integer = (CInt(Regex.Match(clickedTextbox.Name, "\d+").Value) - 1)
        GetNextGame = txtboxnum Mod 9
    End Function

    'altered some code to avoid errors if Option Strict is turned on 
    'also changed order of code to handle the checking of game status
    'etc
    Private Sub TextBoxClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim txtbox As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
        Dim gameStatus As EnumGameStatus
        'added this and the subsequent resume layout to disable
        'repaints every time a text box is enables/disabled
        'while processing the click
        SuspendLayout()
        If _ch = 1 Then
            NextPlayer()
            _currentGameId = GetCurrentGame(txtbox)
            txtbox.Text = _currentplayer
            txtbox.Enabled = False
            gameStatus = CheckWin(_currentGameId)
            If Not gameStatus = EnumGameStatus.Incomplete Then
                Select Case gameStatus
                    Case EnumGameStatus.Draw
                        MarkGameDraw(_currentGameId)
                    Case EnumGameStatus.XWin
                        MarkGameXWin(_currentGameId)
                    Case EnumGameStatus.OWin
                        MarkGameOWin(_currentGameId)
                End Select
                TotalCheckWin()
            End If
            'check next game is incomplete and disable all others
            'else enable all incomplete games
            _currentGameId = GetNextGame(txtbox)
            If _gameStatus(_currentGameId) = EnumGameStatus.Incomplete Then
                Disable_All()
                Enable_Game(_currentGameId)
            Else
                Disable_All()
                For gameId As Integer = 0 To 8
                    If _gameStatus(gameId) = EnumGameStatus.Incomplete Then
                        Enable_Game(gameId)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
        Hidden_txtbox.Focus()
        ResumeLayout()
        Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub initializeClickHandlers()
        For Each txtbox As TextBox In games
            AddHandler txtbox.Click, AddressOf TextBoxClickHandler
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is there a way to send you The all code,I have added all the code, but i'm not to sure that you know how Ultimate Tic Tac Toe works.

Comment: If i was to goto the top left corner square and in the top right i put an "O" the next enabled square will be the top right one, not the same square as you have  it doing.

Comment: No problem. The main purpose of thus if course is to show how code can be shortened. If you have time,  have a look at it and if you have any questions, don't hesitate to email me at the address in my user profile.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some for loops.
Create list for all your textboxes

```
Dim listOfTextBox as new list(of TextBox)


    For value As Integer = 1 To 10
    dim textbox as new TextBox
    textbox.Name= "TextBox"+value.tostring 
    listOfTextBox.add(textbox) 

        If (value = 10) Then
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

After that you can change Enable_A() to something like this:

```
listofTextBoxes.ForEach(Sub(o)
                                o.BackColor = Color.White
                                o.Enabled = True
                                o.Name = "TextBoxId"
                            End Sub)
```

Comment: This is just an example but you should take this and apply it to all of your code.

Comment: listofTextBoxes.ForEach(Sub(o)
                                    o.BackColor = Color.White
                                    o.Enabled = True
                                End Sub)

Comment: Use Name instead of ID

Comment: Offir Pe'er there is one problem I found and that's that `listOfTextBox.Add(textbox)` doesn't work, I've done 2 sets of testing which were msgbox and listbox they both woked code `msgbox(textbox.name)` and `listbox1.items.add(textbox.name)`